# Any tool for easily parse a config file on Linux?

Tags: linux, parsing, configuration-files, redhat

I need a tool that allows me to parse a config file and request some data from it.

The format of the config file is **free** (it can be INI, XML, and so on) but the more human-friendly, the better.

Here is a sample config file (using XML, but it could be anything: i don't mind the format):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <name>Some name</name>
  <description>Some description</description>
</configuration>
```

The tool usage should be something like:

```
[ereOn@server ~]$ the_tool config.xml "string(/configuration/name)"
Some name
[ereOn@server ~]$ the_tool config.xml "string(/configuration/description)"
Some description
```

Do you know any Linux tool that can do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do that with python (.ini-Style config files): http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

**EDIT**:
You could just use sed with regexes, too (but forget the "easily" then, if you're not experienced a bit with sed :P).

Answer (score 3):

A simple config format style (variable=value, one per line) is easily parsed with grep and cut.

For example config.conf file:

```
name=Some Name
description=Some Description
```

Then to get a specific value:

```
# grep "^name=" config.conf | cut -d= -f2
Some Name
# grep "^description=" config.conf | cut -d= -f2
Some Description
```

It's easy and very cheap (doesn't require any additional binaries to be installed as grep and cut are standard on any Linux...).

You could also write a simple bash script wrapper if you want a single command to provide the value you need:

```
#!/bin/bash

CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/config.conf

if [ ! -e $CONFIG_PATH ]; then
  echo "$CONFIG_PATH not found"
  exit 1
fi

if [ $# -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Syntax: $0 \"<variable name>\""
  exit 1
else
  VARNAME="$1"
  eval "grep \"^$VARNAME=\" $CONFIG_PATH | cut -d= -f2"
fi
```

Then all you need to do is call it like this:

`# yourscript.sh variable_name`

Answer (score 2):

Perl has [modules for many different formats of config file](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=config&mode=all) including [JSON](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aJSON) and [INI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Config%3a%3aINI)

Answer (score 0):

[jc](https://github.com/kellyjonbrazil/jc) in combination with [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/) can help you parse many different config formats in almost the same way:

xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <name>Some name</name>
  <description>Some description</description>
</configuration>
```

```bash
cat config.xml | jc --xml | jq -r '.configuration.name'
# Some name
```

yaml:

```yaml
configuration:
  name: Some name
  description: Some description
```

```bash
cat config.yml | jc --yaml | jq -r '.[0].configuration.name'
# Some name
```

ini:

```ini
[configuration]:

name=Some name
description=Some description
```

```bash
cat config.ini | jc --ini | jq -r '.configuration.name'
# Some name
```

json:

```json
{
  "configuration":{
    "name": "Some name",
    "description":"Some description"
  }
}
```

```bash
cat config.json | jq -r '.configuration.name'
# Some name
```